# Svelte JavaScript In style

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

In my style component I have a class that changes the backgound color of a button as follows:

```html
<style>
.button:global(:nth-child(2)) {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

My issue is that I don't want the nth-child hard-coded, I would like it to be a variable, as seen below.

```html
<script>
let x = 5
</script>

<style>
.button :global(:nth-child(x)) {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not going to convert this into an answer, someone else can, but here's *the first result on DuckDuckGo* for "svelte variables in style tag": https://svelte.school/tutorials/how-to-use-variables-in-style-tags-in-svelte, and it seems to be what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, the only thing that **is** possible to use the style attribute to set properties (or custom properties) on an element, but these can not be used as an argument to `nth-child`